# How to expose drop-area of jquery ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists.
A and B

For example:

```
<div class="list">
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <ul class="items">
    <li>Item 1</item>
    <li>Item 1</item>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="list">
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <ul class="items">
    <li>Item 1</item>
    <li>Item 1</item>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is drag one item from .items and drop to another .list or .items.

Basically my drop area should be on parent element as well, but items must be stored within .items element.

Looks like I need to use jquery ui droppable on parent element and then append to .items element. But if there is standart option for jquery ui sortable, would help a lot.

Comment: found any solutions?